# Spring model attribute gets null within the request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a page with pagination links at the top.
When I click the pages it takes me from record 1-50, 51-100 and so on.
I am having issue when i click the second action like when I click page # 2 @ModelAttribute values gets null.

this is tha page url: `http://localhost:8080/tax/taxedYear.html?p=2`

It takes me to spring controller class with /taxedYear.html and the method is as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/taxedYear.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)    
public ModelAndView showTaxResults(@ModelAttribute("criteria")
    Criteria criteria, Model model, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) { 

    String src = criteria.getSource();
    System.out.println("src === "+src);
    //....
    //
    }
```

When it is called anything from criteria is null. The same method is called from the previou page and it works fine.
This happens only when I click the page urls which also calls the same method in the controller and sends page # in addition.

Answer (score 1):

From [Spring reference:](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args)

> An @ModelAttribute on a method argument indicates the argument should be retrieved from the model. If not present in the model, the argument should be instantiated first and then added to the model.

Model is populated by controller. You assume that the model remains the same when second call is made, but apparently your assumption is wrong. Because Spring initializes the model, I believe you thought it's persistent. And it is the reasonable way, model shouldn't be persistent among HTTP calls.